# What's the difference between use_authtok and try_first_pass or use_first_pass in pam_unix?

Tags: linux, pam

The [documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/pam_unix.8.html) for `try_first_pass` and `use_first_pass` sounds reasonable enough:

```
       try_first_pass
           Before prompting the user for their password, the module
           first tries the previous stacked module's password in case
           that satisfies this module as well.

       use_first_pass
           The argument use_first_pass forces the module to use a
           previous stacked modules password and will never prompt the
           user - if no password is available or the password is not
           appropriate, the user will be denied access.
```

`try_first_pass` uses the previously entered password if there was one and prompts otherwise. `use_first_pass` uses the previously entered password if there was one and fails otherwise. But there is also a `use_authtok` option:

```
       use_authtok
           When password changing enforce the module to set the new
           password to the one provided by a previously stacked password
           module (this is used in the example of the stacking of the
           pam_cracklib module documented below).
```

What is `use_authtok` for? Is it just the same as `try_first_pass`, or the same as `use_first_pass`, or is it something else entirely?

Comment: not exactly sure, but the text there seems to hint that `use_authtok` would only work when _changing_ the password, not when authenticating. The man page example has `password   required   pam_cracklib.so ...`  and then `password   required   pam_unix.so use_authtok ...`

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I would caution that `pam_unix` behavior does not match the documentation for `try_first_pass` and `use_first_pass`.  See https://github.com/linux-pam/linux-pam/issues/357

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I've been able to figure out thanks to [Andrew's comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/687772/whats-the-difference-between-use-authtok-and-try-first-pass-or-use-first-pass-i?noredirect=1#comment1300370_687772), [Tomáš Mráz's explanation](https://github.com/linux-pam/linux-pam/issues/357#issuecomment-842077475), and an examination of [the source code](https://github.com/linux-pam/linux-pam/blob/master/modules/pam_unix/pam_unix_passwd.c):

- Despite what the documentation implies, `try_first_pass` does absolutely nothing when applied to `pam_unix.so`.
- `use_authtok` does exactly the same thing as `use_first_pass` when applied to `pam_unix.so`: It uses the previously entered password if there was a previously entered password AND that password meets the previous modules' password quality requirements. Otherwise, it strictly fails.
- If neither `use_first_pass` nor `use_authtok` is applied to `pam_unix.so`, behavior depends on whether a password was previously entered. If there was not a previously entered password, `pam_unix.so` graciously prompts for one. If there was, `pam_unix.so` behaves as if `use_first_pass` or `use_authtok` was set.

This is all for `pam_unix.so`. Beware that `try_first_pass`, `use_first_pass`, and `use_authtok` work differently in other PAM modules.