# Error when using use_authtok and use_first_pass with pam_pwhistory, but not when I use try_first_pass?

Tags: pam, passwd

RHEL 7.9

I have a question similar to [What's the difference between use_authtok and try_first_pass or use_first_pass in pam_unix?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/687772/whats-the-difference-between-use-authtok-and-try-first-pass-or-use-first-pass-i)

I have created a new local file in /etc/pam.d called system-auth-local and symlinked /etc/pam.d/system-auth to that file.  /etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac is still present.

When I use these lines in /etc/pam.d/system-auth-local:

```
password requisite pam_pwhistory.so use_authtok remember=5 retry=3
password include system-auth
```

any attempt as root to use 'passwd' to change anyone's password fails.

```
# passwd user1
Changing password for user user1.
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
```

It also doesn't work if I try as the user:

```
$ passwd
Changing password for user user1
Changing password for user1
(current) UNIX password:
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
```

NOTE: in the above, I did NOT enter anything at the (current) UNIX password prompt. The error popped up prior to me typing anything.

The permissions on /etc/shadow are 640, / is mounted rw, and I rebooted several times (these are suggestions regarding how to resolve the token manipulation error I found)

I tried changing /etc/pam.d/system-auth-local to the below:

```
password requisite pam_pwhistory.so use_first_pass remember=5 retry=3
password include system-auth
```

But I got the same errors.

However, when I tried this:

```
password requisite pam_pwhistory.so try_first_pass remember=5 retry=3
password include system-auth
```

I was able to change passwords using 'passwd'

Can someone please provide an explanation of what is going on and why the first two arguments don't work but the third one does?

Thanks